# MongoDB search query with &

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My document has the structure as shown below.

```
{ 
  id: '2eacea29-915c-4573-91c3-98815143b722',
  name: 'hey look at all this &'
}
```

And I've tried perform the search query `db.myCollection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"\&\""}})`.
But the result is null.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$regex`.

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "&"
  }
})
```

Here is the working demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CBVBH1HYcJx

Comment: Hey Nenad, Thanks a lot!
But I have to use search. I cannot use $regex